# R- apply a function to a multiple data frames, data frame names to be pulled from another dataframe

Tags: r

I have seen may posts regarding this topic but sadly not able to find what I am trying to achieve. I have three dataframes (data1,data2,data3) as below:

```
first_name=c("xxx", "yyy", "zzz")
address=c("ca", "sa", "la")
data1=data.frame(first_name,address)

first_name=c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc")
address=c("ca", "sa", "la")
data2=data.frame(first_name,address)

first_name=c("abc", "bab", "cac")
address=c("ca", "sa", "la")
data3=data.frame(first_name,address)
```

I need to apply a function to above 3 dataframes(not only these 3 there can be many more, it has to be dynamic). The data frames are present in my environment. Also, there is a metadata dataframe which contains the names of this dataframes along with other columns.

```
name = c(2, 3, 5) 
entity = c("aa", "bb", "cc") 
tablename = c("data1", "data2", "data3") 
metadata = data.frame(name, entity, tablename)
```

From the above metadata, I need to extract the values of tablename column, which are basically dataframes that are already present in my environment. I need to apply a function to these dataframes and generate different outputs for each.
Here is my function(example):

```
myfunction <- function(data) {
if(class(data)[1] != 'data.frame' && class(data)[1] != 'data.table') {
stop('Invalid input: data should be either data.frame or data.table')
} else {
variable <- names(data)
class <- sapply(data, class)
contents <- data.frame(variable, 
                       class)
return(contents)  
}
}
```

But When I am tying to use "list" and "lapply" it not working.

```
tablelist <- list(sqldf("select tablename from metadata group by 1"))
lapply(tablelist,myfunction)
```

Above code is appying my function to the tablename column itself instead of values of tablename column.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Explore the difference between: `[ ]` and `[[  ]]`. IMHO you want `[[`.
Short you can do `lapply(tablelist, myfunction)` because `lapply()`dives into the list.

Comment: I tried doing simply    lapply(tablelist,myfunction)     but it did not work as myfunction only takes dataframe or data table as input..

Comment: Just use `mydflist <- list(df1, df2, df3, ...)` to create a list of your dataframes, then use `lapply(mydflist, myfunction)` to loop through them.

Comment: its a list..but the function only accepts dataframe or datatable..

Comment: @LeoP. could do that but I need to make it automated, as in I would not know the tablenames in metadata table.. I need to extract whatever tables (data frames) are present in the metadata table column "tablename" and apply my function to all those tables/dataframes.

Comment: @jogo lapply     (metadata$tablename, function(tablename) dqcontents(sqldf(paste0("select ", tablename, " from metadata group by 1"))) -  this query is searching for "data1" which is a dataframe name as column name. "Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : no such column: data1"

Comment: @Debanjan Ghosal: Do you have strings in your column `metadata$tablename`?

Comment: @LeoP.    yes, there are various dataframe names like data1,data2, data3 etc

Comment: @jogo I will do the same now. Thanks..

Comment: yes that is right @jogo , i just checked, the class of the column tablename is "logical"..

Comment: No, no, you got it differently. I do not want to put the three dataframes in metadata dataframe. Suppose in any normal scenario, there are tables and is a metadata table. The metadata table has name of all the tables. Now, I will pull names of all the tables from the metadata table and apply my function to those tables. That is all I want to do. @jogo

Comment: Apologies. I didnt understand you correctly. Yes, I want what you mentioned.. @jogo

Comment: So first correct your question! ... what you need to solve the problem is the function `get()`. So you can do: `lapply(metadata$tablename, function(dfname) myfunction(get(dfname)))`   
But a better way would be if the many dataframes are not in the workspace but in a list of dataframes.

Comment: @jogo What is "dfname" in your above code? I cannot pass the name of the dataframe manually..It has to be pulled from values of tablename column..like I mentioned in question..

Comment: @DebanjanGhosal Sorry I forgot the `as.character()` (data.frame() has StringsAsFactors=TRUE as default). This I tested: `lapply(as.character(metadata$tablename), function(dfname) myfunction(get(dfname)))`

Comment: Thanks a lot @jogo. It works, but seems like the output of applying the function to each dataframe is horizontally merged one after another! How do I send each output to different data frames? Sorry for bothering so much...I am new to R so not able to achive this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it:

```
data1 <- data.frame(first_name=c("xxx", "yyy", "zzz"), address=c("ca", "sa", "la"))
data2 <- data.frame(first_name=c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc"), address=c("ca", "sa", "la"))
data3 <- data.frame(first_name=c("abc", "bab", "cac"), address=c("ca", "sa", "la"))

metadata <- data.frame(name = c(2, 3, 5), entity = c("aa", "bb", "cc"), tablename = c("data1", "data2", "data3") )

myfunction <- function(data) {
  if(class(data)[1] != 'data.frame' && class(data)[1] != 'data.table') {
    stop('Invalid input: data should be either data.frame or data.table')
  } else {
    variable <- names(data)
    class <- sapply(data, class)
    contents <- data.frame(variable, 
                           class)
    return(contents)  
  }
} 

lapply(as.character(metadata$tablename), function(dfname) myfunction(get(dfname)))
```

`as.character()` is needed because `data.frame()` has `StringsAsFactors=TRUE` as default.

Or you change to `StringsAsFactors=FALSE`:

```
metadata <- data.frame(name = c(2, 3, 5), entity = c("aa", "bb", "cc"), 
                       tablename = c("data1", "data2", "data3") , stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
lapply(metadata$tablename, function(dfname) myfunction(get(dfname)))
```

You can put the result in a list: `L <- lapply(...)` You can see one Element of the list by (e.g.) `L[[1]]` And you can name the elements of the list to access the elements by name:

```
names(L) <- as.character(metadata$tablename)
L[["data1"]]   # or
L$data1
```

Comment: what about if my function accepts two parameters? like if  have a function to compare two tables which takes two input parameters.. how do I use the `lapply(metadata$tablename, function(dfname) myfunction(get(dfname)))`, If I want to achieve this like two parameters looking like `metadata$tablename, metadata1$tablename`.. How to use like this?

Comment: Depends on what you want, something like `mapply('+', 1:5, 5:1)` or `outer(1:5, 5:1, FUN='+')`. One problem to solve with your function for `outer`: "FUN is called with these two extended vectors as arguments" (from the documentation of `outer`).